# Cloning an android activity dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, clone, android-view

I'm creating an application with a rather dynamic UI that allows users to add/change the positions of its views and layouts dynamically. If the user decides that current UI design satisfies him he would be able to save all views(`buttons/labels/switches/etc.`) of the activity into a list of "saved" activities. Is there a possible way to clone an activity or at least save the positions of all views and layouts? I saw that views have functions `.getX()` and `.getY()` but as far as I understood it is only within a layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

I found a solution that works. I created a simple Sqlite Database the stored the XY locations/names/text/id of all my views in to a table dynamically and then displayed them in a list of 'saved' configurations. The hard part is creating dynamically again all the views after you get the DB. If there is a request, I can also put some code up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a base-activity, that has the functionality that both of your Activities need. This functionality would have to be slightly abstracted so that both activites could use this functionality by extending this BaseActivity and use it for their individual purposes.

If you post some code (the part of code both of your activities should have), I could update my answer to show you how that would look like in your case.

**Further**,

Step #1: Open the old project in Android Studio.

Step #2: Open the new project in Android Studio, choosing to open it in a new window (rather than the window you have from Step #1).

Step #3: Drag and drop the Java class files from the old project into the new project.

Step #4: Drag and drop the resources used by those Java classes from the old project into the new project.

Step #5: Find the  elements from the manifest of the old project and copy those into the same basic location in the manifest of the new project.

Comment: I don't want to transfer activities from one project to another. I would like to save the layout of the activity dynamically (let's say on a button click) into something like a listview of saved instances of the activity layout.